# how do I turn off google analytics while using angulartics

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, angulartics

I'm using Google Analytics with Angulartics in my webapp.  I was getting a lot of noise from my app when developing locally so I turned off Google Analytics by just not loading the script if I am running on `localhost` like this:

```
<script>
if (window.location.host.indexOf('localhost') < 0) { 
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){

        /* Google Analytics Code snippet*/

}
</script>
```

but now it occurs to me that Angulartics may blow up if this script is not loaded and my analytics object does not exist.  I am not seeing any errors, so it would seem that Angulartics handles this case well, but since I am not familiar with the Angulartics internals I want to be sure before I ship this piece of code.

Will this cause any issues?  Have I overlooked anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I did some digging through the [Angulartics source](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-google-analytics) and it appears that they do indeed check for the existence of `window.ga` in all instances on the following lines:

- [24](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-google-analytics/blob/master/lib/angulartics-ga.js#L24)
- [38](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-google-analytics/blob/master/lib/angulartics-ga.js#L38)
- [44](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-google-analytics/blob/master/lib/angulartics-ga.js#L44)
- [81](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-google-analytics/blob/master/lib/angulartics-ga.js#L81)
- [108](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-google-analytics/blob/master/lib/angulartics-ga.js#L108)

so it would appear my initial assumption was correct and Angulartics does seem to handle cases in which Google Analytics is unavailable without blowing up.